# GAE Backend fails to respond to start request

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This is probably a truly basic thing that I'm simply having an odd time figuring out in a Python 2.5 app.

I have a process that will take roughly an hour to complete, so I made a backend.  To that end, I have a backend.yaml that has something like the following:

```
-name: mybackend
 options: dynamic
 start: /path/to/script.py
```

(The script is just raw computation.  There's no notion of an active web session anywhere.)

On toy data, this works just fine.

This used to be public, so I would navigate to the page, the script would start, and time out after about a minute (HTTP + 30s shutdown grace period I assume, ).  I figured this was a browser issue.  So I repeat the same thing with a cron job.  No dice.  Switch to a using a push queue and adding a targeted task, since on paper it looks like it would wait for 10 minutes.  Same thing.

All 3 time out after that minute, which means I'm not decoupling the request from the backend like I believe I am.

I'm assuming that I need to write a proper Handler for the backend to do work, but I don't exactly know how to write the Handler/webapp2Route.  Do I handle `_ah/start/` or make a new endpoint for the backend?  How do I handle the subdomain?  It still seems like the wrong thing to do (I'm sticking a long-process directly into a request of sorts), but I'm at a loss otherwise.

Comment: did you deploy with "appcfg backends <app> start"?

Comment: The backend has already been started and the instances spin up and spin down again after each request. I don't think it would be able to serve the push-queue requests otherwise, since the subdomain for the backend wouldn't exist.

Comment: The only thing that seems a bit weird is that your script is just raw computation.  Can you wrap it in an HTTP request handler that kicks off your computation?

I don't really know if that's the problem, but its the only main difference between yours and what I have.

Comment: According to the list of reasons why your backend might shutdown:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview.html#Shutdown
Possibly you've hit a memory limit.  I've also seen other complaints about backends not running, so you might be experiencing some transient App Engine problems.

Comment: Hmmm, going to try to change the instance class and see if it lasts twice as long.  Python is currently having issues on GAE, so we'll see.

Comment: @dragonx If you make an answer for this question, I'll give you credit for it since it the memory-limit suggestion allowed a more open interpretation of what was going on

Comment: nah, I didn't solve it, but it's good to know you did.  Thanks for posting the answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the root cause ended up being doing the following in the script itself:

```
models = MyModel.all()
for model in models:
    # Magic happens
```

I was basically taking for granted that the query would automatically batch my Query.all() over many entities, but it was dying at the 1000th entry or so.  I originally wrote it was computational only because I completely ignored the fact that the reads can fail.

The actual solution for solving the problem we wanted ended up being "Use the map-reduce library", since we were trying to look at each model for analysis.